# C++11 function parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

Is it possible to somehow make functions (C++11) which will accept different parameters depending on the first one?
Lets say, I need the following behavior:

```
enum TypeFill{Solid, Gradient1, Gradient2};

void fill(const TypeFill t,  Type1 param1 = NULL, Type2 param2 = NULL){
  if (t == Solid){
       fillSolid(param1);
  } else if (t == Gradient1){
       fillGradient1(param1, param2);
  } else if (t == Gradient2){
       fillGradient2(param1, param2);
  }
}

private:
fillSolid(Brush b){};                
fillGradient1(Color c1, Color c2){};
fillGradient2(Color c1, Color c2){};
```

Call example:

```
fill(Solid, Brush(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)){};                
fill(Gradient1, Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), Color(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)){};
fill(Gradient2, Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), Color(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)){};
```

Just wonder if this possible. I feel that may be something possible to do with enable_if and template specializations, but may be not...

Comment: What is `enum TypeFill<Solid, Gradient1, Gradient2>;`?... and in the rest of the code, I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Since the type of fill would need to be known at compile time, how would something like this be better than `solidFill(Brush)`, `gradientFill(Color, Color)` etc? Of course there are lots of ways to expose such an API; I 'm just picking the most obvious simple case as a point of reference.

Comment: @Nawaz: They want to allow or disallow different signatures for `fill` based on the value of its first argument (which is not possible, so we 're talking about some moral equivalent).

Comment: @Jon solidFill and gradientFill - is simpler and is an option. But I want to know how to achive described behavior.

Comment: Do you want to select something at compile time based on a value that will be known at run time? Just askin'.

Comment: value be known at compile time also (be const).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sane thing here would be to use the three functions you have directly. If you absolutely must have the syntax:

```
fill(Solid, Brush(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
fill(Gradient1, Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), Color(1.0, 1.0, 0.0));
fill(Gradient2, Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), Color(1.0, 1.0, 0.0));
```

You can get it from two overloads:

```
void fill(TypeFill t, Brush b) {
    assert(t == Solid);
    fillSolid(b);
}

void fill(TypeFill t, Color c1,  Color c2) {
  switch(t) {
  case Gradient1:
    fillGradient1(c1, c2);
    break;
  case Gradient2:
    fillGradient2(c1, c2);
    break;
  default:
    assert(false);
    break;
  }
}
```

and if you want a single function badly enough to throw out type-safety along with any possibility of debugging errors, you can use C-style varargs:

```
void fill(TypeFill t, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, t);
  switch(t) {
  case Gradient1:
    fillGradient1(va_arg(ap, Color), va_arg(ap, Color));
    break;
  case Gradient2:
    fillGradient2(va_arg(ap, Color), va_arg(ap, Color));
    break;
  case Solid:
    fillSolid(va_arg(ap, Brush));
    break;
  default:
    assert(false);
    break;
  }
  va_end(ap);
}
```

Be careful that you do not fall afoul of the `va_arg` requirements as detailed in C++11 §5.2.2/7:

> When there is no parameter for a given argument, the argument is passed in such a way that the receiving function can obtain the value of the argument by invoking `va_arg` (18.10). The lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the argument expression. An argument that has (possibly cv-qualified) type `std::nullptr_t` is converted to type `void*` (4.10). After these conversions, if the argument does not have arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, pointer to member, or class type, the program is ill-formed. Passing a potentially-evaluated argument of class type (Clause 9) having a nontrivial copy constructor, a non-trivial move contructor, or a non-trivial destructor, with no corresponding parameter, is conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics. If the argument has integral or enumeration type that is subject to the integral promotions (4.5), or a floating point type that is subject to the floating point promotion (4.6), the value of the argument is converted to the promoted type before the call. These promotions are referred to as the *default argument promotions*.

Answer (score 2):

It boils down to having several overloads, so the simplest way would be to define:

- `fillSolid(Brush b)`
- `fillGradient(Color c1, Color c2)`

In this design you'd need the enum value to be known at compile time anyway in each particular call, so there's not much to gain.

OTOH you'd probably want to redesign your code so that instead of an enum you'd have an actual abstraction for `Fill` with different implementations like `Solid`, `Gradient1`, `Gradient2`, etc, each with its own data set.

---

Follow-up: This is an example of a syntax that you COULD get with templates:

```
fill<Solid>::call(Brush(1.0, 0.0, 0.0));               
fill<Gradient1>::call(Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), Color(1.0, 1.0, 0.0));
fill<Gradient2>::call(Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), Color(1.0, 1.0, 0.0));
```

The enumerator now is a class template parameter, not a function argument, so it's resolved at compile-time and the (member) function signature is able to depend on it.

Comment: Hint: The ONLY thing templates can do is code generation, and you first need an idea what code to generate

Comment: really funny, indeed.

Comment: @Kos while technically yes I dont agree with you on the `only` part. The desired behaviour here could actually be implemented with simple template specialization though I wouldnt consider it appropriate here.

Comment: @tower120 No, why? Simply use function overloading (like proposed in this answere) or inheritance (or both combined, `Fill*` signature will do a `dynamic_cast` the other ones are specificly overloaded). I wont introduce you to an advanced concept if you cant even grasp the basic ones (e.g how to declare an enum...). You will thank me later on.

Comment: @mfukar No Im refusing it because he doesnt knoe some other more basic things. He should read up about those before he goes further. And besides that I wont post an answere here which I consider in all terms bad.

Comment: @tower120 Whats about reading this answere? And please dont tend to demand something from me...

Comment: @tower120 No, I believe what you asked for can't be implemented as in your spec. Templates won't help because it doesn't make sense to have the function signature depend on a run-time value (like a function parameter) - template instantiation is done during compile time.

Comment: @Kos And what about variable argument list, can't it be implemented with it? First argument make const - so compiler can eliminate if condition.

Comment: No, you seem to be mixing up template instantiation and function call: they happen at different moments in time.

Comment: Without templates, I mean :) Just: void fill(const TypeFill t,  ...)